# Why x[i][:]=x[:][i] where x is a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I am working on a list of lists and accessing columns has been very confusing.

Let's assume x is defined as following:

```
  x = [[int(np.random.rand()*100) for i in xrange(5)] for x in xrange(10)]
  pprint.pprint(x)
```

> ```
> [[86, 92, 95, 78, 68],
>  [76, 80, 44, 30, 73],
>  [48, 85, 99, 35, 14],
>  [3, 84, 50, 39, 47],
>  [3, 7, 67, 28, 65],
>  [19, 13, 98, 53, 33],
>  [9, 97, 35, 25, 89],
>  [48, 3, 48, 5, 1],
>  [21, 40, 72, 61, 62],
>  [58, 43, 84, 69, 26]]
> ```

Now, both `x[1][:]` and `x[:][1]` yield the same result:

```
[76, 80, 44, 30, 73]
```

Can someone explain why?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a list of lists? You have NumPy! You're using NumPy's random number generator! Use an array! If you had an array instead of a list of lists, `x[i, :]` and `x[:, i]` would do what you want.

Comment: Because I have lists of different sizes and types and the example here is only for illustration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is pretty simple to understand if you break up the two indexing operations of each of your expressions into separate pieces.

- `x[1]` will be the second value from your list of lists (the list `[76, 80, 44, 30, 73]`).
- `x[1][:]` is a copy of `x[1]` (a slice that spans the whole list).
- `x[:]` is a (shallow) copy of `x` (the list of lists).
- `x[:][1]` is the second value from the copied list of lists, which is the same object as `x[1]`.

So, the two expressions work out to be equal. Note that because the first expression copies the list (with the `[:]` slice at the end), they're not both the same object (`x[1][:] is x[:][1]` will be `False`).

If you were using a 2D numpy array, you'd get different behavior, since you can slice in arbitrary dimensions (using slightly different syntax):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[86, 92, 95, 78, 68],
              [76, 80, 44, 30, 73],
              [48, 85, 99, 35, 14],
              [3, 84, 50, 39, 47],
              [3, 7, 67, 28, 65],
              [19, 13, 98, 53, 33],
              [9, 97, 35, 25, 89],
              [48, 3, 48, 5, 1],
              [21, 40, 72, 61, 62],
              [58, 43, 84, 69, 26]])

print(x[1,:]) # prints the values of the second row: [76 80 44 30 73]
print(x[:,1]) # prints the values of the second column: [92 80 85 84  7 13 97  3 40 43]
```

This may be what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I would have definitely used np.array if it wasn't for different types of lists that I have in my original list.

Answer (score 3):

`x[:][1]` is the whole array row 1 and `x[1][:]` is all row 1 of `x` so they both point to the same row.

```
In [2]: x[:]
Out[2]: 
[[86, 92, 95, 78, 68],
 [76, 80, 44, 30, 73],
 [48, 85, 99, 35, 14],
 [3, 84, 50, 39, 47],
 [3, 7, 67, 28, 65],
 [19, 13, 98, 53, 33],
 [9, 97, 35, 25, 89],
 [48, 3, 48, 5, 1],
 [21, 40, 72, 61, 62],
 [58, 43, 84, 69, 26]]
In [3]: x[1]
Out[3]: [76, 80, 44, 30, 73]

In [4]: x[1][:]
Out[4]: [76, 80, 44, 30, 73]
```

Using `x[:]` is often used if you wanted to store a copy of `x` in a variable and **not** just a reference to it:

```
In [6]: x1 = x[:]

In [7]: x1
Out[7]: 
[[86, 92, 95, 78, 68],
 [76, 80, 44, 30, 73],
 [48, 85, 99, 35, 14],
 [3, 84, 50, 39, 47],
 [3, 7, 67, 28, 65],
 [19, 13, 98, 53, 33],
 [9, 97, 35, 25, 89],
 [48, 3, 48, 5, 1],
 [21, 40, 72, 61, 62],
 [58, 43, 84, 69, 26]]
```

Creating a copy:

```
In [11]: x1 = x[:]
In [12]: id(x1)       # different objects so different id's
Out[12]: 140130415845104    
In [13]: id(x)
Out[13]: 140130400510176
```

Creating a reference:

```
In [14]: x1 = x

In [15]: id(x)   # same object so same id's
Out[15]: 140130400510176

In [16]: id(x1)
Out[16]: 140130400510176
```

Answer (score 1):

`x[1][:]` is saying first get `x[1]` which is the first object in the list.  In this case it is a list.  Then by adding `[:]` to that, you are saying to return all list objects from that first list.  So it returns the whole first list object from your main list of lists.

`x[:][1]` is first saying by `x[:]` to return the whole list.  Then by adding `[1]` you are saying to only return the first item in the whole list.